# Как подавить предупреждение анализатора кода для всех DataTable, которые используются без вызова Dispose?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, static-analysis

У меня есть методы, которые формируют и возвращают таблицы `DataTable`. Анализатор кода на эти методы выдаёт предупреждение такого вида:

`Warning    1   CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'DataTableSaver.ReadDataTable(Stream)', object 'ret' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'ret' before all references to it are out of scope.`

Класс `DataTable` не имеет своего собственного метода `Dispose`, этот метод унаследован от `MarshalByValueComponent` и ничего существенного не делает. Поэтому я не хочу загромождать код заведомо ненужными вызовами, лишь бы анализатор не ругался. Соответственно, чтобы убрать ложную тревогу, необходимо подавить это предупреждение.

В идеале я хотел сделать так: пометить сборку:

```
[assembly:SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2000:DisposeObjectsBeforeLosingScope", Target="System.Data.DataTable")]
```

Не сработало. Путём экспериментов я выяснил, что предупреждение можно подавить, только если либо у каждого метода, где оно возникает, прописать `SupressMessage`, либо сделать кучу почти одинаковых записей в `GlobalSupressions.cs`. Но мне такое решение кажется не вполне корректным. Во-первых, это нарушает принцип DRY. Во-вторых, совместно с `DataTable` у меня могут в тех же методах использоваться другие типы данных, требующие вызова `Dispose`, и подавив предупреждение таким способом, я могу пропустить связанные с этим ошибки. При корректном решении анализатор кода должен игнорировать именно `DataTable`, а не конкретные места в моём коде.

Ещё на сайте Microsoft написано про какой-то editorconfig, но при этом не разъясняется, что это за editorconfig, как его создать, шаблона такого элемента в Visual Studio тоже нет. Я попробовал положить в директорию проекта файл .editorconfig с таким содержимым:

```
dotnet_code_quality.CA2000.excluded_symbol_names = System.Data.DataTable
```

Тоже не работает. Причём не работает, даже если прописать значение, взятое из атрибута в `GlobalSupressions.cs`. Т.е., в editorconfig не работает даже то, что можно сделать с использованием атрибутов.

Comment: У вас опечатка в `System.Data.DataTble`, может быть, это причина?

Comment: Попробовал, перепроверил с исправленным - нет.

Comment: А покажите скриншот, как выглядит предупреждение, можно?

Comment: А как? В комментарий не вставляется.

Comment: Ну может быть добавьте в вопрос. И ещё, как вы подключаете анализаторы? Хочу попробовать воспроизвести.

Comment: На проекте контекстное меню - Run Code Analysis. Ничего специально не подключаю. Правда, я когда-то Power Commands ставил, но даже без них в Visual Studio есть в главном меню анализ кода, где есть эта кнопка.

Comment: Странно, не могу воспроизвести. А какой у вас target framework? Есть что-то интересное в .csproj?

Comment: Хм, попробуйте в .editorconfig добавить префикс `T:`: `dotnet_code_quality.CA2000.excluded_symbol_names = T:System.Data.DataTable` — как-то так, вроде, судя по документации

Comment: 1. Не помогло. 2. А где найти документацию, где это написано?

Comment: А что за класс DataTable? Ваш или дотнетовский? Попробуйте его перенезвать, возможно конфликт имён.

Comment: Документацию я тут читал: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-quality-rule-options вероятно ещё что упускаем, читал про диагонали

Comment: Про сам .editorconfig можно почитать на официальном сайте: https://editorconfig.org/ там должен быть пустой шаблон для проекта, вероятно у вас не хватает заголовка вроде `[*.cs]` или ещё чего. А вообще этот .editorconfig весьма удобная штука, мы используем на своем проекте, правда для подавления сообщений анализатора ещё не приходилось, только для форматирования. Если потратить немного (или много) времени на конфигурирование, то можно добиться одинакового форматирования кода для всех синтаксических аспектов, на ревью практически не будет замечаний к стилю, что раньше было проблемой, т.к. ...

Comment: ... команда достаточно разношёрстная. Это такая альтернатива распространению файла с настройками для студии, но действующая только на один проект и без необходимости принудительного импортирования + действующая в большинстве редакторов и IDE, а не только в студии. В общем всем рекомендую :)